# How do I import current price from site into excel?

Tags: excel, web-services, bitcoin, auto-update, stock

Currently I use this in excel to import a stock price:
[image]

This is from Yahoo Finance and is simple to use, I can press CTRL-ALT-F9 to auto-update all cells and have the latest price populate the cell.

How would I import a changing number from another site?
I have tried using methods such as "Data>Get & Transform Data>From Web" with no success.

What I am trying to acomplish is to have an excel cell which shows the current price on http://preev.com/ and updates to the latest price when I press CTRL-ALT-F9

Comment: Are you open to an answer that involves writing code?

Comment: Sure, as long as it's all integrated into excel. The more simple the better, but anything working is better than nothing :)

Comment: Your chance of getting the data you want would go up if you were using Python in addition to Excel. (JS and Ruby would also work, but Python is what I know.) Does Excel have any functions for importing external data other than `WEBSERVICE()`?

Comment: Does the quote need to come from that page?  I have another source for BTC data, and code written to obtain it using an api.

Comment: It could come from another source, I haven't coded in Python in a while but I'm open to using it if it works well with excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `UDF` written in `VBA` to return the current bit coin spot price.  As written, it will update with ctrl-alt-F9.  The default return is the `spot` price.  It will also return `buy` or `sell` with the appropriate arguments.

Don't forget to set the references as shown in the code.

On the worksheet:

```
=CurrBitCoinPrice()
```

**Regular Module**

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to: Microsoft WinHTTP services, Version 5.1
'                  Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Function CurrBitCoinPrice(Optional BSSp As Long = 3) as Currency
        '1:  Buy
        '2:  Sell
        '3:  Spot

Application.Volatile

    Dim httpRequest As WinHttpRequest
    Dim sResponse(2) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim sType
    Const sInfo As String = "?currency=USD"
    Dim vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long

sType = Array("buy", "sell", "spot")

Const sUrl As String = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/"


For I = 0 To 2
Set httpRequest = New WinHttpRequest
With httpRequest
    .Open "Get", sUrl & sType(I) & sInfo
    .Send
    .WaitForResponse

    sResponse(I) = .ResponseText
End With
Set httpRequest = Nothing
Next I

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Pattern = "\d*\.?\d+"
    .Global = False
End With
ReDim vRes(0 To 1, 1 To 3)
    vRes(0, 1) = "Buy"
    vRes(0, 2) = "Sell"
    vRes(0, 3) = "Spot"

    For I = 0 To 2
        If RE.Test(sResponse(I)) = True Then
            Set MC = RE.Execute(sResponse(I))
            vRes(1, I + 1) = MC(0)
        End If
    Next I

CurrBitCoinPrice = vRes(1, BSSp)

End Function
```

Comment: I tried it and got an error, when I clicked okay the text on top was highlighted, I placed it in a red box: https://i.imgur.com/4ZnSVgC.png

Comment: Kudos for having supplied the relevant information (many do not).  The second and third lines of the macro (`Set Reference`) indicate what you failed to do.

Comment: @Karl Any luck after setting the references?

Comment: I got it working, thank you very much! I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Since this seems to have answered your question, if you could mark my response as the answer (little check mark at the upper left), I would appreciate it.

Comment: Done! When I click the cell displaying the bitcoin price and I select the "Dollar" number format, it centers the numbers and does not show the dollar sign. How do I fix this?

Comment: The function is returning a variant/string data type since it was adapted from something else I've been using. One method is to change the return type to `Currency` or to `Double`, and you should be fine.  I edited my response to show that change.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this solution and looking same for your problem:

[excel-convert-external-links-to-values](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2988-excel-convert-external-links-to-values.html)

if you dont prefer this method, I will search such a kind of different ways